# Is it possible to inject the machine code got using fasm into x64 binary?

Tags: assembly, x86-64, fasm

I want to get the machine code from x64 assembly on runtime.
and inject this machine code into x64 binary.

I have got the machine code from x86 assembly using the FASM on runtime.

```
  FasmNet fasm = new FasmNet();
  fasm.Clear();
  fasm.AddLine("use32");
  fasm.AddLine("mov eax, 1");
  fasm.AddLine("retn");

  var byteCode = new byte[0];
  try
  {
     byteCode = fasm.Assemble();
  }
  catch (FasmAssemblerException ex)
  {
     Console.WriteLine("Error");
  }

  // result
  // b8 01 00 00 00 c3
```

I have done x64 converting with it.
    fasm.AddLine("use64");
I got the same machine code.
I am not sure the machine code got using the fasm will be injected into x64 binary.

I want to know how to get the machine code from x64 assembly on runtime.

Answer (score 3):

> Because Fasm doesn't support the x64.

**No, because the x86-64 machine code for those instructions happens to be identical.**

Try an instruction like `mov rax, -1`, `inc rcx`, or `push r15` that need a REX prefix.  Or a uniquely 64-bit mnemonic/opcode like `movsxd r8, edx`.

Or try to use a removed instruction like `aam`.

---

There are also instructions that are valid in both modes, but that do assemble to different machine code.

`inc eax` can't use the 1-byte encoding because x86-64 repurposed `0x4?` inc/dec register opcodes as REX prefixes.

Or `mov edx, [0x123456]` - note that FASM has to use a ModRM+SIB encoding for the addressing mode because x86-64 repurposed the ModRM-only encoding of `[disp32]` to mean `[RIP + rel32]`.  Leaving only the longer encoding to still encode 32-bit absolute addresses.

Comment: Related, if you're JITing machine code you want to run from inside your process:  [Handling calls to (potentially) far away ahead-of-time compiled functions from JITed code](//stackoverflow.com/q/54947302) or if you can't allocate a buffer within +-2GiB for `call re32`, then [Call an absolute pointer in x86 machine code](//stackoverflow.com/q/19552158)